# UNET doesn't wotk

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, multiplayer

I want to make a multiplayer game, but UNET (the Unity local-served multiplayer solution) doesn't work.

I tried using UNET, but it seems deprecated. Is it still usable somehow? If yes, how can I use it?

**P.S.: The game will be 2D and practically lightweight (it will have a maximum of 2 players), so it won't consume a lot of resources.**

**P.S. 2: I would want the game to have something like a unique code or something for the other player to join.**

*Thank you in advance! ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

that's a cool project you have there and wish you some success.
There are many ways to do what you are asking for.

For example the person who will host the server can share some code to other players(which when decrypted contains the IP address to connect to), or directly the IP address. For example MTI3LjAuMC4xOjIwMDAK is base64 encoding for 127.0.0.1:2000 using only the following lines of code

```
//Encode in base 64
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

More advanced would be you have two servers one for the player to notify that he is hosting a server, and that server would be listed and visible to his friends from the main server which is just listing and checking who can access which servers based on a friend list for example.

and so on....

If it is for a simple project I would probably go with option 1.